# Android Push Notification crash with my own xml settings

Tags: java, android, xml

here is part of my java code in the GCMIntentService:

```
NotificationMan

ager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
int icon = getResources().getIdentifier("ic_launcher", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

int iLayout = getResources().getIdentifier("notification", "layout", context.getPackageName());
RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), iLayout); 
remoteView.setImageViewResource(getResources().getIdentifier("icon", "id", context.getPackageName()), icon);  
remoteView.setTextViewText(getResources().getIdentifier("title", "id", context.getPackageName()), title);  
remoteView.setTextViewText(getResources().getIdentifier("message", "id", context.getPackageName()), message); 

Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
notification.contentView = remoteView; 
notification.contentIntent = intent; 

notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

and below is my notification.xml:

```
rsion="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:padding="3dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="44dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/message"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />

            </LinearLayout>

   </LinearL
```

ayout>

when I send the push notification to devices,then it crash!

I hope use :

```
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
```

cause my AndroidManifest.xml must set

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

could someone point the way to solve this problem?

Comment: whats ur android:minSdkVersion ?

Comment: Please provide a stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
NotificationManager notificationManager;
notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
    context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                                       UnityPlayerActivity.class);

notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent
    .getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                                         R.layout.notification);
remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.title, title);
remoteView.setTextViewText(R.id.message, message);
remoteView.setImageViewResource(R.id.icon, R.drawable.ic_launcher);

NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(intent);

Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
notification.contentView  = remoteView;

notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```